# R tidyverse, arrange after unite

Tags: r, tidyverse

After unite() arrange() organizes numbers like so 1, 10, 11, ..., 19, 2, 20, ...

```
jj <- data.frame(TrainNum = 2100,
             SeqNum = 1:30)
jj %>% 
  unite(tnSn, TrainNum, SeqNum) %>% 
  arrange(tnSn)
```

Has anyone found a work around?

Comment: what r u trying to do? can u please more specific

Comment: When you see numbers sorted alphabetically instead of numerically, that means your column isn't a numeric class, probably `character` or `factor`. (Probably because something you united it with wasn't parseable as a number...). Convert it back to numeric `as.numeric(as.character(tnSn))` to sort it numerically.

Comment: After `unite()`, `tnSn` is a probably a character field. I think you need `arrange(SeqNum)`

Comment: The variable you're trying to `arrange` is not numeric as you have the `_` character when you `unite`. You can try something like this `jj %>% 
  unite(tnSn, TrainNum, SeqNum, remove = F) %>% 
  arrange(SeqNum)` and then remove any columns you don't need. Of course, you can `arrange` before `unite`, but I guess from your question / title that you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
jj <- data.frame(TrainNum = 2100,
         SeqNum = 1:30)
jj %>% 
  mutate(SeqNum = str_pad(SeqNum, width = 2, pad = "0")) 
  unite(tnSn, TrainNum, SeqNum) %>% 
  arrange(tnSn)
```

Worked perfectly!